# tesseract not able to read all digits accurately

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract to recognize numbers from images of a screen taken with a phone camera. I've done some preprocessing of the image: [processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1zma.jpg), and using Tesseract, I'm able to get some mixed results. Using the following code on the above images, I get the following output: "EOE". However, with this image, [processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5q4E.jpg), I get an exact match: "39:45.8"

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

orig_name  = "time3.jpg";
image_name = "time3_.jpg";

img = cv2.imread(orig_name, 0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

img_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255,\
    cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

cv2.imshow('image', img_th)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite(image_name, img_th)

im = Image.open(image_name)

time = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config = "-psm 7")
print(time)
```

Is there anything I can do to get more consistent results?

Comment: You can run connected component analysis and than for each component run the detection.

Answer (score 3):

I did three additional things to get it correct for the first Image.

1. You can set a whitelist for Tesseract. In your case we know that
   there will only charachters from this List **`01234567890.:`**. This
   improves the accuracy significantly.
2. I resized the image to make it easier for tesseract.
3. I switched from psm mode 7 to 11 (Recoginze as much as possible)

---

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

orig_name  = "./time1.jpg";
img = cv2.imread(orig_name)

height, width, channels = img.shape
imgResized = cv2.resize(img, ( width*3, height*3))
cv2.imshow("img",imgResized)
cv2.waitKey()
im = Image.fromarray(imgResized)
time = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config ='--tessdata-dir "/home/rvq/github/tesseract/tessdata/" -c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890.: -psm 11 -oem 0')
print(time)
```

---

**Note:**
You can use `Image.fromarray(imgResized)` to convert an opencv image to a PIL Image. You don't have to write to disk and read it again.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it did improve the accuracy for recognizing digits, but I wanted to clarify if you got a complete read for the first image. With your additional modifications, I got "2408" for the first image and "39 458" for the second image. It seems to be missing the colon and period. Do I need to include the `--tessdata-dir` option?

Comment: Try if it works better with the tessdata option. You need to set oem mode to 0. Whitelisting does not work for tesseract lstm mode (4.0)

Comment: I included all the above options that you suggested: `time = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config ='--tessdata-dir "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/" -c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890.: -psm 11 -oem 0')` and I'm still getting "2408" and "39 458" for the first and second images, respectively. Is there anything else you might suggest that I explore? Perhaps some more pre-processing of the image? Thanks in advance!